# how to create Android application with out action bar in eclipse

Tags: android

am new to android so firstly i start with eclipse.but when i was try to create an application there is a problem at last of creation one error is coming "creates a new android application with an action bar".so how to create an android application with out an actionBar

Comment: Do you want to make your Activity fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

Change your theme in style.xml

```
<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your Activity Theme

using manifest.xml

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/a_string"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

using java,

```
getsupportactionbar().hide()
```